# How to find current utc time in milliseconds inside browser using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting utc time from server (Python) when game is started in milliseconds. I need to show remaining time inside browser. How to find current utc time in milliseconds inside browser using javascript ? ( To convert I can do like `server_utc+54000000 - current_javascript_utc` and then module to get secconds and minutes, game can last 54000000 milliseconds )

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current millisecond time using `+new Date()` or (on newer browsers) `Date.now()`.

However you should also note that there is no guarantee whatsoever that the client's time and the server's time are in sync, so comparing them will be highly error prone.

Comment: yes, but unless the device is running a time sync service it can get out of sync.  Or the user might have the TZ misconfigured even though the client's "wall clock" appears to be correct, which would make the UTC value incorrect.